# Cannot make full html content to PDF from Html div by jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I need your help.
I try to make downloadable pdf file form blog each post in blogger. I have use following code and plugins :

**Plugins:**

```
jQuery v1.11.3
jspdf.js
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id='printpdf'>
..................
Blog Post Content here
.....................
</div>
<div id="editor">
</div>
<button id="btn-pdf" type="button" name="btn-pdf">generate PDF</button>
```

HTML Live URL:
http://ecwebzone.blogspot.in/2015/09/this-is-test-post-of-pdf-creation.html

**Code:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var specialElementHandlers = {
      &#39;#editor&#39;: function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }   
    };

    $(&#39;#btn-pdf&#39;).click(function () {

            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
            var source = $('#printpdf').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(source, 5, 5, {
                'width': 297,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");

    });


  });
</script>
```

After click on the button it will convert few lines of this post like, you check it through my url:

```
Answer the following questions by selecting the most appropriate option.
1. A creative learner refers to one who is
```

Please help me any one. I want to add this option to my each post as namely 'Download post as pdf' in a4 paper size.

I have also try following:

```
<script>
     function downPDF() {
         var doc = new jsPDF(&#39;p&#39;, &#39;in&#39;, &#39;letter&#39;);
         var source = $(&#39;#printpdf&#39;).first();
         var specialElementHandlers = {
             &#39;#editor&#39;: function(element, renderer) {
                 return true;
             }
         };

         doc.fromHTML(
             source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
             0.5,    // x coord
             0.5,    // y coord
             {
                 &#39;width&#39;: 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                 &#39;elementHandlers&#39;: specialElementHandlers
             });

         doc.save('ECNote-files.pdf');
    }
    </script>
```

here output blank only. no text in created pdf.

Comment: In my browser i get an js error for the &#39;-signs. Replacing them with the actual quotation marks removes that error.

Comment: For blogger,  I parse the ' sign to &#39;

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML source i see that the first line with a span has not a <br> after the closing tag but a </div>. So the #printpdf-div is closed after the first span. Replac e the </div> at this position with a <br /> and it should work.

Code:

```
... 1. A creative learner refers to one who is</span> --></div><--
<span style="background-color: white; color: #141823; font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.32px;">(1) very talented in drawing and painting</span><br /> ....
```

Comment: I think you are right. printDoc.fromHTML($('#printpdf').get(0), 0.5, 0.5, {'width': 180}); Can you explain me this line.

Comment: I have update code with: <script>
    function printPDF() {
        var printDoc = new jsPDF();
        printDoc.fromHTML($(&#39;#printpdf&#39;).get(0), 10, 15, {&#39;width&#39;: 180});
        //printDoc.autoPrint();
        printDoc.save(&quot;ec_files.pdf&quot;);
    }
    </script> and I want to make pdf in a4 size with 1inch margin in top, btm,left,right of the document.